# Python issues parsing through a list from an imported csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Ive patched together a script which runs through an imported list of url's and grabs all the 'p' tags from a html section which has the class of 'holder'. It works but it only looks at the first url in from the imported CSV:

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contents = []
with open('list.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents

for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

n = 0
for container in soup.find_all("section",attrs={'class': 'holder'}):
    n += 1
    print('==','Section',n,'==')
    for paragraph in container.find_all("p"):
        print(paragraph)
```

Any ideas how i get it to loop through each url rather than just one?

Comment: Can you show the sample values in your `contents` array?

Comment: Should the last block of your code, i.e. from `n = 0` down, all be indented to be inside of the `for url in contents:` loop? Otherwise you just keep overriding `soup` without ever using it.

Comment: I'm also confused as to why you need `url[0]`, isn't `url at this point just a string containing a single url?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the indentation of your code. The correct one is:

```
contents = []
with open('list.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents

for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    n = 0
    for container in soup.find_all("section",attrs={'class': 'holder'}):
        n += 1
        print('==','Section',n,'==')
        for paragraph in container.find_all("p"):
            print(paragraph)
```

Otherwise you extract the contents of the 'p' tag from the last URL (the previous loop's last value assigned to `soup`.

Comment: One more question: Do you know how would i save the output as a csv rather than print?

Comment: This is a different question and one that is well documented (c.f. [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) ).

Answer (score 0):

You have to indent the `for container in soup.find_all():` loop, try something like this:

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('list.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        page = urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

        n = 0
        for container in soup.find_all("section",attrs={'class': 'holder'}):
            n += 1
            print('==','Section',n,'==')
            for paragraph in container.find_all("p"):
                print(paragraph)
```